# Codeigniter Navbar Adjustment/Alignment Problem

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter, bootstrap-4

I would like to move the Navbar Components/buttons a little bit going to the right. But how? Please thanks! Below is my code from one of the channels in Youtube. Thank you so much!

```html
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" id="header">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>home"><font size="+1.5"><span style="color:#111111;">CAMCS</span></font></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="#"><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>home"><span style="color:#111111;">HOME</span></a></li>
        

        <li class="#"><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>home"><span style="color:#111111;">ABOUT CAMCS</span></a></li>


        <li class="#"><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>home"><span style="color:#111111;">OFFICE OF THE PRINCIPAL</span></a></li>
        <li class="#"><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>home"><span style="color:#111111;">ACADEMICS</span></a></li>
        <li class="#"><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>home"><span style="color:#111111;">ADMISSION</span></a></li>
        <li class="#"><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>home"><span style="color:#111111;">STUDENT BODY</span></a></li>

      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>users/registration"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user", style="color:#111111;"></span> <span style="color:#111111;">CONTACT US</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[HERE IS THE SCREEN SHOT OF MY NAVBAR. PLEASE HELP!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAkmO.jpg)

Please refer to the screenshot

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap 4? The Navbar code you've posted is for Bootstrap 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Bootstrap Spacing.

Add ml-5 in ul class

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-5">
```

You can get reference from here.. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/spacing/